# How to translate a GTK+ app?

Tags: c++, c, internationalization, gtk, gettext

I want to translate my GTK+ application written in C++. I don not have any ideas where to start, I heard about gettext(), but I don't know, how should I use it.

Comment: Read `man xgettext`: after processing your source files by `xgettext` you will get po-file. You must translate it and by `msgfmt` process mo-file with translation for gettext. Of course, `gettext()` must know where to file mo-files, so in beginning of your `main()` you must call function `bindtextdomain`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-question-index.html page, in 1.7. paragraph they explain how you can translate your applications using [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).